# Getting started with swashbuckle for blank web.api in vs2015

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

This is a beginner question.   In 2015 I created a blank web.api project.  I then added Swashbuckle 5.5.3 nuget package.  I created a common controller listed below.

```
namespace StarterApi.Controllers
```

{
    public class CommonController : ApiController
    {

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTestList(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
        try
        {
            //var principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            List<DDLDispValueVM> ctrList = new List<DDLDispValueVM> {
               new DDLDispValueVM { Disp="one", Value="1"},
               new DDLDispValueVM { Disp="two", Value="2"}
            };

            msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ctrList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
        return msg;
    }

}
```

}

When I go to the url I get the swagger screen,  but it is missing the Controller.
See Image.

[image: when I navgate to /swagger url]

I have a GitHub of the project at...
[TestSwashbuckle](http://github.com/ATXGearHead12/TestSwashbuckle)

Here is the SwaggerConfig file

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using StarterApi;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace StarterApi
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    // By default, the service root url is inferred from the request used to access the docs.
                    // However, there may be situations (e.g. proxy and load-balanced environments) where this does not
                    // resolve correctly. You can workaround this by providing your own code to determine the root URL.
                    //
                    //c.RootUrl(req => GetRootUrlFromAppConfig());

                    // If schemes are not explicitly provided in a Swagger 2.0 document, then the scheme used to access
                    // the docs is taken as the default. If your API supports multiple schemes and you want to be explicit
                    // about them, you can use the "Schemes" option as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });

                    // Use "SingleApiVersion" to describe a single version API. Swagger 2.0 includes an "Info" object to
                    // hold additional metadata for an API. Version and title are required but you can also provide
                    // additional fields by chaining methods off SingleApiVersion.
                    //
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "StarterApi");

                    // If your API has multiple versions, use "MultipleApiVersions" instead of "SingleApiVersion".
                    // In this case, you must provide a lambda that tells Swashbuckle which actions should be
                    // included in the docs for a given API version. Like "SingleApiVersion", each call to "Version"
                    // returns an "Info" builder so you can provide additional metadata per API version.
                    //
                    //c.MultipleApiVersions(
                    //    (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(apiDesc, targetApiVersion),
                    //    (vc) =>
                    //    {
                    //        vc.Version("v2", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V2");
                    //        vc.Version("v1", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V1");
                    //    });

                    // You can use "BasicAuth", "ApiKey" or "OAuth2" options to describe security schemes for the API.
                    // See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md for more details.
                    // NOTE: These only define the schemes and need to be coupled with a corresponding "security" property
                    // at the document or operation level to indicate which schemes are required for an operation. To do this,
                    // you'll need to implement a custom IDocumentFilter and/or IOperationFilter to set these properties
                    // according to your specific authorization implementation
                    //
                    //c.BasicAuth("basic")
                    //    .Description("Basic HTTP Authentication");
                    //
                    // NOTE: You must also configure 'EnableApiKeySupport' below in the SwaggerUI section
                    //c.ApiKey("apiKey")
                    //    .Description("API Key Authentication")
                    //    .Name("apiKey")
                    //    .In("header");
                    //
                    //c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                    //    .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                    //    .Flow("implicit")
                    //    .AuthorizationUrl("http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/oauth/dialog")
                    //    //.TokenUrl("https://tempuri.org/token")
                    //    .Scopes(scopes =>
                    //    {
                    //        scopes.Add("read", "Read access to protected resources");
                    //        scopes.Add("write", "Write access to protected resources");
                    //    });

                    // Set this flag to omit descriptions for any actions decorated with the Obsolete attribute
                    //c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();

                    // Each operation be assigned one or more tags which are then used by consumers for various reasons.
                    // For example, the swagger-ui groups operations according to the first tag of each operation.
                    // By default, this will be controller name but you can use the "GroupActionsBy" option to
                    // override with any value.
                    //
                    //c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.HttpMethod.ToString());

                    // You can also specify a custom sort order for groups (as defined by "GroupActionsBy") to dictate
                    // the order in which operations are listed. For example, if the default grouping is in place
                    // (controller name) and you specify a descending alphabetic sort order, then actions from a
                    // ProductsController will be listed before those from a CustomersController. This is typically
                    // used to customize the order of groupings in the swagger-ui.
                    //
                    //c.OrderActionGroupsBy(new DescendingAlphabeticComparer());

                    // If you annotate Controllers and API Types with
                    // Xml comments (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.110).aspx), you can incorporate
                    // those comments into the generated docs and UI. You can enable this by providing the path to one or
                    // more Xml comment files.
                    //
                    //c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());

                    // Swashbuckle makes a best attempt at generating Swagger compliant JSON schemas for the various types
                    // exposed in your API. However, there may be occasions when more control of the output is needed.
                    // This is supported through the "MapType" and "SchemaFilter" options:
                    //
                    // Use the "MapType" option to override the Schema generation for a specific type.
                    // It should be noted that the resulting Schema will be placed "inline" for any applicable Operations.
                    // While Swagger 2.0 supports inline definitions for "all" Schema types, the swagger-ui tool does not.
                    // It expects "complex" Schemas to be defined separately and referenced. For this reason, you should only
                    // use the "MapType" option when the resulting Schema is a primitive or array type. If you need to alter a
                    // complex Schema, use a Schema filter.
                    //
                    //c.MapType<ProductType>(() => new Schema { type = "integer", format = "int32" });

                    // If you want to post-modify "complex" Schemas once they've been generated, across the board or for a
                    // specific type, you can wire up one or more Schema filters.
                    //
                    //c.SchemaFilter<ApplySchemaVendorExtensions>();

                    // In a Swagger 2.0 document, complex types are typically declared globally and referenced by unique
                    // Schema Id. By default, Swashbuckle does NOT use the full type name in Schema Ids. In most cases, this
                    // works well because it prevents the "implementation detail" of type namespaces from leaking into your
                    // Swagger docs and UI. However, if you have multiple types in your API with the same class name, you'll
                    // need to opt out of this behavior to avoid Schema Id conflicts.
                    //
                    //c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();

                    // Alternatively, you can provide your own custom strategy for inferring SchemaId's for
                    // describing "complex" types in your API.
                    //  
                    //c.SchemaId(t => t.FullName.Contains('`') ? t.FullName.Substring(0, t.FullName.IndexOf('`')) : t.FullName);

                    // Set this flag to omit schema property descriptions for any type properties decorated with the
                    // Obsolete attribute 
                    //c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();

                    // In accordance with the built in JsonSerializer, Swashbuckle will, by default, describe enums as integers.
                    // You can change the serializer behavior by configuring the StringToEnumConverter globally or for a given
                    // enum type. Swashbuckle will honor this change out-of-the-box. However, if you use a different
                    // approach to serialize enums as strings, you can also force Swashbuckle to describe them as strings.
                    // 
                    //c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

                    // Similar to Schema filters, Swashbuckle also supports Operation and Document filters:
                    //
                    // Post-modify Operation descriptions once they've been generated by wiring up one or more
                    // Operation filters.
                    //
                    //c.OperationFilter<AddDefaultResponse>();
                    //
                    // If you've defined an OAuth2 flow as described above, you could use a custom filter
                    // to inspect some attribute on each action and infer which (if any) OAuth2 scopes are required
                    // to execute the operation
                    //
                    //c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();

                    // Post-modify the entire Swagger document by wiring up one or more Document filters.
                    // This gives full control to modify the final SwaggerDocument. You should have a good understanding of
                    // the Swagger 2.0 spec. - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md
                    // before using this option.
                    //
                    //c.DocumentFilter<ApplyDocumentVendorExtensions>();

                    // In contrast to WebApi, Swagger 2.0 does not include the query string component when mapping a URL
                    // to an action. As a result, Swashbuckle will raise an exception if it encounters multiple actions
                    // with the same path (sans query string) and HTTP method. You can workaround this by providing a
                    // custom strategy to pick a winner or merge the descriptions for the purposes of the Swagger docs 
                    //
                    //c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());

                    // Wrap the default SwaggerGenerator with additional behavior (e.g. caching) or provide an
                    // alternative implementation for ISwaggerProvider with the CustomProvider option.
                    //
                    //c.CustomProvider((defaultProvider) => new CachingSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider));
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    // Use the "InjectStylesheet" option to enrich the UI with one or more additional CSS stylesheets.
                    // The file must be included in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's
                    // "Logical Name" is passed to the method as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.InjectStylesheet(containingAssembly, "Swashbuckle.Dummy.SwaggerExtensions.testStyles1.css");

                    // Use the "InjectJavaScript" option to invoke one or more custom JavaScripts after the swagger-ui
                    // has loaded. The file must be included in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's
                    // "Logical Name" is passed to the method as shown above.
                    //
                    //c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "Swashbuckle.Dummy.SwaggerExtensions.testScript1.js");

                    // The swagger-ui renders boolean data types as a dropdown. By default, it provides "true" and "false"
                    // strings as the possible choices. You can use this option to change these to something else,
                    // for example 0 and 1.
                    //
                    //c.BooleanValues(new[] { "0", "1" });

                    // By default, swagger-ui will validate specs against swagger.io's online validator and display the result
                    // in a badge at the bottom of the page. Use these options to set a different validator URL or to disable the
                    // feature entirely.
                    //c.SetValidatorUrl("http://localhost/validator");
                    //c.DisableValidator();

                    // Use this option to control how the Operation listing is displayed.
                    // It can be set to "None" (default), "List" (shows operations for each resource),
                    // or "Full" (fully expanded: shows operations and their details).
                    //
                    //c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);

                    // Specify which HTTP operations will have the 'Try it out!' option. An empty paramter list disables
                    // it for all operations.
                    //
                    //c.SupportedSubmitMethods("GET", "HEAD");

                    // Use the CustomAsset option to provide your own version of assets used in the swagger-ui.
                    // It's typically used to instruct Swashbuckle to return your version instead of the default
                    // when a request is made for "index.html". As with all custom content, the file must be included
                    // in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's "Logical Name" is passed to
                    // the method as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.CustomAsset("index", containingAssembly, "YourWebApiProject.SwaggerExtensions.index.html");

                    // If your API has multiple versions and you've applied the MultipleApiVersions setting
                    // as described above, you can also enable a select box in the swagger-ui, that displays
                    // a discovery URL for each version. This provides a convenient way for users to browse documentation
                    // for different API versions.
                    //
                    //c.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();

                    // If your API supports the OAuth2 Implicit flow, and you've described it correctly, according to
                    // the Swagger 2.0 specification, you can enable UI support as shown below.
                    //
                    //c.EnableOAuth2Support(
                    //    clientId: "test-client-id",
                    //    clientSecret: null,
                    //    realm: "test-realm",
                    //    appName: "Swagger UI"
                    //    //additionalQueryStringParams: new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "foo", "bar" } }
                    //);

                    // If your API supports ApiKey, you can override the default values.
                    // "apiKeyIn" can either be "query" or "header"                                                
                    //
                    //c.EnableApiKeySupport("apiKey", "header");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `SwaggerConfig` class?

Comment: The swaggerConfig class has been added.

Answer (score 3):

4 items are still needed:

- Uncomment the line in the SwaggerConfig Register() method that says `c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());`
- Add a private static string property to your SwaggerConfig class that specifies the path for the XML

  ```
  private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
  {
      var path = string.Format(@"{0}bin\StarterAPI.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
      return path;
  }
  ```
- Generate XML by changing your build options as follows:  in Project Properties, Build tab, Output section CHECK the XML documentation file and make it read: **bin\StarterAPI.xml**  Notice that it is the same path as generated in the previous step...this links the build XML creation to the SwaggerConfig consumer.
- Lastly, annotate your controller methods with /// tags , [HttpGet] annotations and [Route("")] annotations. The sample below looks mostly complete:

  ```
  // GET api/Stuff/17205
  /// <summary>
  /// Returns Stuff record based on supplied Stuff_Id
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="stuffId"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("api/Stuff/{stuffId}")]
  public Stuff_Request Get(int stuffId) {
  ```

Answer (score 2):

With Swashbuckle version 5.6.0 (actually you probably need only Swashbuckle.Core nuget package) you can configure it very easy.

Create SwaggerConfig class that looks like this:

```
public static class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.EnableSwagger(Configure).EnableSwaggerUi(ConfigureUi);

    }

    static void Configure(SwaggerDocsConfig config)
    {
        config.SingleApiVersion("V1", "MichalBialecki.com.Swagger.Example");
        config.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
    }

    static void ConfigureUi(SwaggerUiConfig config)
    {
        config.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
        config.DisableValidator();
    }
}
```

You also need to register it in Startup.cs:

```
SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
```

And that's it. It works for me.